# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference when tomcat server run in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, tomcat

I'm running tomcat server in eclipse,(org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference) these error occur.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse xml with &. You should use `&amp; for &` while parsing.

In your case when tomcat is starting in eclipse it's finding some XML where & is not escaped. That XML either be present in your application or in some jar.